# VSTS - uploading via an excel macro and getting @mentions to work

Tags: vba, excel, tfs, azure-devops, mention

I am using VSTS and would like numerous people to get sent the notification when a work task is created.

I am creating a lot of stencils that can just automate and upload work tasks through the TEAM add-in in excel, but don't know how to make the "@mention" function work.

I have written all sorts of styles of syntax in the history field, then publish but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone figured this out?

Cheers Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is like:

`<a href="#" data-vss-mention="version:2.0,userid"></a>`

You can To get the **userid** through User [Entitlements-Lists REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list):

`GET https://{accountName}.vsaex.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=4.1-preview`

Comment: Thanks Starian, It has certainly made the UserID a hyperlink in the VSTS comment box when it is uploaded from the excel macro, But it still doesn't work, I have used multiple version of the user name. but not alas.

Comment: @DavidHollingsworth What's the actual value you specified in history field? What do you mean multiple version of the user name, but not alias? What's the version of your excel?

Comment: So I used "<a href="#" data-vss-mention="version:2.0,userid">@david hollingsworth</a> I also used david.hollingsworth, davidhollingsworth, davidhollingsworth@domain.com.au. It comes up as a hyperlink in VSTS in the history field, but it doesn't send a notification to the intended user. Excel version 16   (note** The hyperlink against my name just goes to the project backlog page)

Comment: @DavidHollingsworth Do you replace the userid to actual value? You don't need to specify the dispalyname, `<a href="#" data-vss-mention="version:2.0,userid"></a>`. The important is the userid.

Comment: Hey Starian, you wouldn't know the syntax to up upload a Hyperlink to VSTS from Excel would you?