# Ping (@) user in Azure DevOps comment

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-workitem

I have the method below that posts a comment to a work-item in Azure DevOps.

How can i `@` a user in the comment?

The Two examples below just posts a string that is `@firstName lastName`and not tagging the user.

```
pMessage = "@User you need to take a look at this workitem"

pMessage = "@firstName lastName <mail> you need to take a look at this workitem"

public async Task PingUser(List<int> pId, string pMessage, VssConnection pConnection)
{
    WorkItemTrackingHttpClient client = pConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

    foreach (var id in pId)
    {
        await client.UpdateWorkItemAsync(
            new JsonPatchDocument()
            {new JsonPatchOperation(){
                Operation = Operation.Add,
                Value = pMessage,
                Path = "/fields/System.History",
            }}, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very agree with Shayki's answer. You can also refer to this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103616/vsts-uploading-via-an-excel-macro-and-getting-mentions-to-work . If it is not work for you, feel free to leave comment there:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you perform Get operation you can see the format you need:

```
var wi = workitemClient.GetWorkItemAsync("project", id).Result;
```

The `wi.Fields["System.History"]` value is:

[image]

So the format is:

```
<a href="#" data-vss-mention="version:2.0,userid"></a>
```

Replace the `userid` with the User Id, to get it you can use [User Entitlements - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/rest/api/azure/devops/memberEntitlementManagement/User%20Entitlements/List?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) Rest API.

Comment: You can also find the ID by manually mentioning a specific user in a comment and then inspecting it in the Browser