# Programmatically add @mention for Active Directory User Account in on-prem Azure DevOps Server work item comment (Jan, 2021)

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019, mention

I administer an on-premises instance of Azure DevOps Server (ADS) 2019 1.1 (Patch 7) running on a closed network. The ADS instance is running in a Windows Active Directory (AD) domain. All ADS users are granted access based on their AD user account. Each AD user account specifies their intranet email address.

I have a requirement to send a notification to the "Assigned To" person's AD email address for specific user stories in a specific project on the first Monday of each month.

The hard part is getting the @mention to resolve to the AD user account so that ADS sends the notification.

How do I get ADS take my @mention and resolve it to an Active Directory user id?

See my MRE in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three S.O. items address aspects of the issue, but my minimal, reproducible example below pulls it all together into a sample working solution

**Past S.O. Q&A**

[Mentioning a user in the System.History (July, 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378893/mentioning-a-user-in-the-system-history)

[VSTS - uploading via an excel macro and getting @mentions to work (March 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103616/vsts-uploading-via-an-excel-macro-and-getting-mentions-to-work/49104734#49104734)

[Ping (@) user in Azure DevOps comment (Oct 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558388/ping-user-in-azure-devops-comment)

I decided to implement this requirement such that ADS sends the notification based on an @mention added programmatically like this:

- On the ADS Application server, create a scheduled task that runs on the first of each month
- The scheduled task runs a program (C# + ADS REST api console app installed on the app server) that locates the relevant user stories and programmatically adds an @mention to a new comment for the user story's "Assigned To" user account. The program runs under a domain admin account that is also a "full control" ADS instance admin account.

**My Minimum Reproducible Example**

**Output**

And, the email notification is sent as expected.

[image]

**Code**

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace AdsAtMentionMre
{

    class Program
    {
        // This MRE was tested using a "free" ($150/month credit) Microsoft Azure environment provided by my Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription.
        // I estabished a Windows Active Directory Domain in my Microsoft Azure environment and then installed and configured ADS on-prem.
        // The domain is composed of a domain controller server, an ADS application server, and an ADS database server.

        const string ADS_COLLECTION_NAME_URL = "http://##.##.##.###/aaaa%20bbbb%20cccc%20dddd";
        const string ADS_PROJECT_NAME = "ddd eeeeee";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!TestEndPoint())
                {
                    Environment.Exit(99);
                }

                // GET RELEVANT USER STORY WORK IDS

                ClsUserStoryWorkIds objUserStoryWorkIds = new ClsUserStoryWorkIds(ADS_COLLECTION_NAME_URL, ADS_PROJECT_NAME);

                // FOR EACH USER STORY ID RETRIEVED, ADD @MENTION COMMENT TO ASSIGNED PERSON

                if (objUserStoryWorkIds.IdList.WorkItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    ClsAdsComment objAdsComment = new ClsAdsComment(ADS_COLLECTION_NAME_URL, ADS_PROJECT_NAME);

                    foreach (ClsUserStoryWorkIds.WorkItem workItem in objUserStoryWorkIds.IdList.WorkItems)
                    {
                        if (objAdsComment.Add(workItem))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Comment added to ID {0}", workItem.Id));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Comment NOT added to ID {0}", workItem.Id));
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

                Exception innerException = e.InnerException;

                msg.AppendLine(e.Message);
                msg.AppendLine(e.StackTrace);

                while (innerException != null)
                {
                    msg.AppendLine("");
                    msg.AppendLine("InnerException:");
                    msg.AppendLine(innerException.Message);
                    msg.AppendLine(innerException.StackTrace);
                    innerException = innerException.InnerException;
                }

                Console.Error.WriteLine(string.Format("An exception occured:\n{0}", msg.ToString()));
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }

        private static bool TestEndPoint()
        {
            bool retVal = false;

            // This is a just a quick and dirty way to test the ADS collection endpoint. 
            // No authentication is attempted.
            // The exception "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." 
            // represents success because it means the endpoint is responding

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ADS_COLLECTION_NAME_URL);
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // find out if this site is up and BTW, don't follow a redirector
                request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
                request.Timeout = 30000;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                if (!e1.Message.Equals("The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."))
                {
                    throw;
                }

                retVal = true;
            }

            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

**ClsUserStoryWorkIds.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace AdsAtMentionMre
{

    public class ClsUserStoryWorkIds
    {
        ClsResponse idList = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Get all the users story ids for user stories that match the wiql query criteria
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="adsCollectionUrl"></param>
        /// <param name="adsProjectName"></param>
        public ClsUserStoryWorkIds(string adsCollectionUrl, string adsProjectName)
        {
            string httpPostRequest = string.Format("{0}/{1}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1", adsCollectionUrl, adsProjectName);

            // In my case, I'm working with an ADS project that is based on a customized Agile process template.
            // I used the ADS web portal to create a customized process inherited from the standard ADS Agile process.
            // The customization includes custom fields added to the user story:
            // [Category for DC and MR] (picklist)
            // [Recurrence] (picklist)

            ClsRequest objJsonRequestBody_WiqlQuery = new ClsRequest
            {
                Query = string.Format("Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' and [System.TeamProject] = '{0}' and [Category for DC and MR] = 'Data Call' and [Recurrence] = 'Monthly' and [System.State] = 'Active'", adsProjectName)
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objJsonRequestBody_WiqlQuery);

            // ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback: In my environment, we use self-signed certs, so I 
            // need to allow an untrusted SSL Certificates with HttpClient
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient
            //
            // UseDefaultCredentials = true: Before running the progran as the domain admin, I use Windows Credential
            // Manager to create a Windows credential for the domain admin:
            // Internet address: IP of the ADS app server
            // User Name: Windows domain + Windows user account, i.e., domainName\domainAdminUserName
            // Password: password for domain admin's Windows user account

            using (HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                    (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
            }))
            {
                HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //todo I guess I should make this a GET, not a POST, but the POST works
                HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), httpPostRequest)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };

                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result)
                {
                    httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    string jsonResponse = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    this.IdList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsResponse>(jsonResponse);
                }
            }
        }

        public ClsResponse IdList { get => idList; set => idList = value; }

        /// <summary>
        /// <para>This is the json request body for a WIQL query as defined by</para>
        /// <para>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1</para>
        /// <para>Use https://json2csharp.com/ to create class from json request body sample</para>
        /// </summary>
        public class ClsRequest
        {
            [JsonProperty("query")]
            public string Query { get; set; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <para>This is the json response body for the WIQL query used in this class.</para> 
        /// <para>This class was derived by capturing the string returned by: </para>
        /// <para>httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result</para>
        /// <para> in the CTOR above and using https://json2csharp.com/ to create the ClsResponse class.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public class ClsResponse
        {
            [JsonProperty("queryType")]
            public string QueryType { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("queryResultType")]
            public string QueryResultType { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("asOf")]
            public DateTime AsOf { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("columns")]
            public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("workItems")]
            public List<WorkItem> WorkItems { get; set; }
        }

        public class Column
        {
            [JsonProperty("referenceName")]
            public string ReferenceName { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }

        public class WorkItem
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**ClsAdsComment.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace AdsAtMentionMre
{
    class ClsAdsComment
    {
        readonly string adsCollectionUrl;
        readonly string adsProjectName

        public ClsAdsComment(string adsCollectionUrl, string adsProjectName)
        {
            this.adsCollectionUrl = adsCollectionUrl;
            this.adsProjectName = adsProjectName;
        }

        public bool Add(ClsUserStoryWorkIds.WorkItem workItem)
        {
            bool retVal = false;

            string httpPostRequest = string.Empty;
            string httpGetRequest = string.Empty;
            string json = string.Empty;

            string emailAddress = string.Empty;
            string emailAddressId = string.Empty;

            #region GET ASSIGNED TO METADATA BY GETTING WORK ITEM

            httpGetRequest = string.Format("{0}/{1}/_apis/wit/workitems/{2}?fields=System.AssignedTo&api-version=5.1", this.adsCollectionUrl, this.adsProjectName, workItem.Id);

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                    (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
            }))
            {

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(httpGetRequest).Result)
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    ClsJsonResponse_GetWorkItem objJsonResponse_GetWorkItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsJsonResponse_GetWorkItem>(responseBody);

                    if (objJsonResponse_GetWorkItem.Fields.SystemAssignedTo == null)
                    {
                        // If there is not a assigned user, skip it
                        return retVal;
                    }

                    // FYI: Even if the A.D. user id that is in the assigned to field has been disabled or deleted
                    // in A.D., it will still show up ok. The @mention will be added and ADS will attempt to
                    // send the email notification
                    emailAddress = objJsonResponse_GetWorkItem.Fields.SystemAssignedTo.UniqueName;
                    emailAddressId = objJsonResponse_GetWorkItem.Fields.SystemAssignedTo.Id;
                }
            }

            #endregion GET ASSIGNED TO METADATA BY GETTING WORK ITEM

            #region ADD COMMENT

            StringBuilder sbComment = new StringBuilder();
            sbComment.Append(string.Format("<div><a href=\"#\" data-vss-mention=\"version:2.0,{0}\">@{1}</a>: This is a programatically added comment.</div>", emailAddressId, emailAddress));
            sbComment.Append("<br>");
            sbComment.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss tt"));

            httpPostRequest = string.Format("{0}/{1}/_apis/wit/workitems/{2}/comments?api-version=5.1-preview.3", this.adsCollectionUrl, this.adsProjectName, workItem.Id);

            ClsJsonRequest_AddComment objJsonRequestBody_AddComment = new ClsJsonRequest_AddComment
            {
                Text = sbComment.ToString()
            };

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objJsonRequestBody_AddComment);

            // Allowing Untrusted SSL Certificates with HttpClient
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                    (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
            }))
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), httpPostRequest)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };

                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessge = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result)
                {
                    httpResponseMessge.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    // Don't need the response, but get it anyway 
                    string jsonResponse = httpResponseMessge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    retVal = true;
                }
            }

            #endregion ADD COMMENT

            return retVal;
        }

        // This is the json request body for "Add comment" as defined by 
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
        // Use https://json2csharp.com/ to create class from json body sample
        public class ClsJsonRequest_AddComment
        {
            [JsonProperty("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <para>This is the json response body for the get work item query used in the Add method above.</para> 
        /// <para>This class was derived by capturing the string returned by: </para>
        /// <para>string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;</para>
        /// <para> in the Add method above and using https://json2csharp.com/ to create the ClsJsonResponse_GetWorkItem class.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public class ClsJsonResponse_GetWorkItem
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("rev")]
            public int Rev { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("fields")]
            public Fields Fields { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("_links")]
            public Links Links { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }

        public class Avatar
        {
            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }

        public class Links
        {
            [JsonProperty("avatar")]
            public Avatar Avatar { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("self")]
            public Self Self { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("workItemUpdates")]
            public WorkItemUpdates WorkItemUpdates { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("workItemRevisions")]
            public WorkItemRevisions WorkItemRevisions { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("workItemComments")]
            public WorkItemComments WorkItemComments { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("html")]
            public Html Html { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("workItemType")]
            public WorkItemType WorkItemType { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("fields")]
            public Fields Fields { get; set; }
        }

        public class SystemAssignedTo
        {
            [JsonProperty("displayName")]
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("_links")]
            public Links Links { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("uniqueName")]
            public string UniqueName { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("imageUrl")]
            public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("descriptor")]
            public string Descriptor { get; set; }
        }

        public class Fields
        {
            [JsonProperty("System.AssignedTo")]
            public SystemAssignedTo SystemAssignedTo { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }

        public class Self
        {
            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }

        public class WorkItemUpdates
        {
            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }

        public class WorkItemRevisions
        {
            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }

        public class WorkItemComments
        {
            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }

        public class Html
        {
            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }

        public class WorkItemType
        {
            [JsonProperty("href")]
            public string Href { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```